# Rails - send XML in controller without view

Tags: ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to send some XML (with right Content-type) on a specific request.
The action does not take care of the `:format` information, and can be called with or without format (like /my_action.html, /my_action, /my_action.php)

This code works perfectly :

```
class MyController
  def my_action
    @root = "root"
    render(:template => 'my_xml', :formats => [ :xml ])
  end
end
```

And `my_xml.xml.erb` looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<<%= @root %>>
  <status value="ok"/>
</<%= @root %>>
```

Everything works fine, but I find this is very unreadable.

Is there any method to directly send XML from controller, like this :

```
def my_action
  render(:xml => { "root" => { "status" => { "value" => "ok" } } }.to_xml)
end
```

(The hash is not the solution, I know, but this is just to show what I expect for syntax).

Regards

Comment: Have you tried: `render :my_xml, format: :xml`?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-xml